# CSS Make div to fill its parent but not to stretch it

Tags: html, css

I have this html structure http://jsfiddle.net/aAXNm/

```
<div id="mainCont">
<div id="stretchParent">
    This div should make its parent bigger
</div>
<div id="fillParent">
    <span>TagItem</span>
    <span>TagItem</span>
    <span>TagItem</span>
    <span>TagItem</span>
    <span>TagItem</span>
    <span>TagItem</span>
</div>
```

And I need the layout to behave like this: The `#mainCont` div has `display:inline-block;` and it should change its `width` according to the `#stretchParent` div. That is all working just fine, but I also need th div `#fillParent` to fill its parent, but not to make the parent grow.

So I have the first situation in the fiddle and I need to get the second one. Do you have any idea?

Thanks

Comment: Like this: http://jsfiddle.net/aAXNm/3/ ?

Comment: Maybe I haven't written my idea clearly enough. Simply I need the mainCont to be as small as possible, but large enough to hold the stretchParent div. And the fillParent div should be as big as possible, but not larger than stretchParent div

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Without changing the layout, and without fixing any static width.
the solution is simple.

```
#mainCont
{
    position: relative;
}

#fillParent
{
    position: absolute;
}
```

take a look here:
http://jsfiddle.net/aAXNm/8/

Comment: Nice,fast and clean...Thank you very much

Comment: But there is one unpleasant thing. In my case it doesn't matter, but changing position to absolute will take the div from html structure therefore all divs "behind" this one in code will appear higher, maybe covered by this div and it may be problem. Here is an example http://jsfiddle.net/aAXNm/9/

Comment: you are right. other issues will need more thinking. but for now, this is a good answer.